# Magento 2 How to get only one field data in collection

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, collection, model

I want to get only one field data in my custom module collection.   For ex:

getting following data in collection:

```
Array
   (
[0] => Array
    (
        [banner_id] => 1
        [banner_title] => Banner 1
        [banner_image] => banner_banner/4/_/4.jpg
        [banner_status] => 0
        [banner_link] => http://google.com
        [banner_sortorder] => 1
    )

)
```

getting this array in  collection response. I need only one value in collection response **banner_image**. I don't want all the data in collection response.  How can i do that?

Is there any method  that allows me to fetch only that specific field data instead of loading entire collection?

I want following result only:

```
   Array
   (
   [0] => Array
    (

        [banner_image] => banner_banner/4/_/4.jpg

    ),
   [2] => Array
    (

        [banner_image] => banner_banner/2/_/892.jpg

    )

)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you just try this?

```
$collection = $customObject->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('banner_image');
```

`addFieldToSelect('column_name')` will work here I think.

Comment: Will it take low time to generate the response?   or it will take same time to load?

Comment: This is the ideal way to select any column from the collection. It will take the same time to load. The only way I guess better than this is to use SQL query, which is not a proper way out.

Answer (score 11):

**Magento has an inbuilt function on [`Magento\Framework\Data\Collection`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Collection.php#L341) which provide a specific field value from the collection.**

You have to use `getColumnValues($colName)` for getting the specific field value

`$collectionObject->addFieldToSelect('banner_image')->getColumnValues('banner_image')`

Comment: Will it take low time to generate the response?   or it will take same time to load?

Comment: And if I want to get multiple columns?

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution :-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
    $collection = $categoryCollection->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('name','MyCards');
    if($collection->count()) {
        return $collection->getFirstItem();
    }else{
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: Using above code you are filtering the collection which is not going to work.  It will show only one value i want entire collection of banner image not only one value.filter will not work.  Just check my question again.  I have updated what output i am expecting in collection result.